# Change img src when browse and select file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, src

I am trying to capture div content and save it as an image. That div content contains image over an image. The base image will remain the same, and when the user browses and selects an image file it will display over the base image. Now when user will press button I am capturing that div content.

The problem is that the first time, when the default image is over a base image, and press submit button it will capture both image and convert it into a new image.

After that when the user browses and selects a new image it will display over base image, but when pressing button it will generate new image of only base image and the user selected image is not coming on captured image.

```html
<script>
    $(function() { 
        $("#proceed").click(function() { 
            html2canvas($("#wrap"), {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    theCanvas = canvas;
                    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                    window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
                }
            });
        });
    }); 

    //display user uploaded image
    var loadFile = function(event) {
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
</script>

<input type="file" onchange="loadFile(event)">
<input type="button" value="Capture" id="proceed"/>

<div id="wrap">
    <img src="1.png"> //base image
    <div id="draggable">
        <img id="output" src="admin/images/allproduct/no_image.png" /> //user selected image
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same task like yours using AngualrJS. This framework has some advanced features like Directives and Filters.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc
You can manage DOM and everything very easily. Please check that.